# Круговая сортировка

Tags: mysql

```
Select id FROM calen WHERE id >= '3'
Select id FROM calen WHERE id < '3'
```

Выводит 3 4 5 6 1 2

Можно ли вывести такой результат одним запросом?

order by field - не подойдёт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это не подойдет ?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/214d6/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
create VIEW `generator_16` AS select 0 AS `n` union all select 1 AS `1` union all select 2 AS `2` union all select 3 AS `3` union all select 4 AS `4` union all select 5 AS `5` union all select 6 AS `6` union all select 7 AS `7` union all select 8 AS `8` union all select 9 AS `9` union all select 10 AS `10` union all select 11 AS `11` union all select 12 AS `12` union all select 13 AS `13` union all select 14 AS `14` union all select 15 AS `15`;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select n from generator_16 order by n<3,n
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/214d6/1/0)**:

```
|  N |
|----|
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
|  0 |
|  1 |
|  2 |
```

работает потому-что для 0,1,2 n<3 === 1 иначе 0

Comment: То, что надо. Спасибо!