# Сортировка таблицы по двум параметрам в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Всем привет. Есть таблица id, title, sort.

В таблице 50 значений. Из них 20 значений заполненны полем sort от 1 до 20, остальные нет, значение равно 0. Как отсортировать таблицу по следующему условию.
Сначало сортируем по sort, а потом по title sort со значением 0

Comment: Круговая сортировка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/338365/%d0%9a%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table
 order by if(sort=0,2,1), sort, title
```

`if` задает условие, если sort <> 0, то он возвращает 1, если равен - то 2. таким образом первыми оказываются записи с sort<>0.

Comment: Можете пояснить что такое sort=0,2,1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY sort = 0, title

+-------+------+
| title | sort |
+-------+------+
| a     |    1 |
| b     |    2 |
| b     |    3 |
| a     |    0 |
| b     |    0 |
| g     |    0 |
| r     |    0 |
| z     |    0 |
+-------+------+
```